# ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax - Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi I am working on mysql database with node js. Much of the data get inserted but at this point the query stuck, I don't know why. I tried `mysql.escape()` and `utf8.encode()` but still the same error.

**This is my query**

```js
                ms_connect.query("INSERT INTO `companies_jobs` VALUES (null, '"+mysql.escape(data[i].title)+"','"+mysql.escape(data[i].link)+"','"+mysql.escape(data[i].date)+"','"+mysql.escape(data[i].level)+"','"+mysql.escape(data[i].category)+"','"+mysql.escape(data[i].function)+"','"+mysql.escape(data[i].loc)+"','"+mysql.escape(data[i].timing)+"','"+mysql.escape(data[i].company)+"','"+JSON.stringify(time)+"','"+JSON.stringify(date)+"',"+1+")", function(err, row){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(data[i]);
                        throw err;
                    } else{
                        i++;
                        s();
                    }
                })
```

**I am trying to insert this data into the database :**

```js
[{
  category: 'Sales',
  company: '',
  date: 'Posted on 12/06/2018',
  function: '',
  level: 'Students',
  link: 'https://career5.successfactors.eu/career?career%5fns=job%5flisting&company=LiMySLive&navBarLevel=JOB%5fSEARCH&rcm%5fsite%5flocale=en%5fUS&career_job_req_id=13305&selected_lang=es_ES&jobAlertController_jobAlertId=&jobAlertController_jobAlertName=&_s.crb=fl08QG2oV1akJFW%2fWVQ4Ol50v%2bs%3d',
  loc: 'Chile (CL)',
  timing: 'full time',
  title: 'Alumno en Practica'
}]
```

But due to some reason, I get this error :

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Alumno en Practica'',''https://career5.successfactors.eu/career?career%5fns=job%' at line 1

This is how the table structure :

[image]

Comment: Add the table definition as text, please.

Comment: I see `JSON.stringify(time)` and `JSON.stringify(date)` in your query, but the key _time_ is not included in the data you want to insert into the database. Did you perhaps mean `JSON.stringify(data[i].timing)` and `JSON.stringify(data[i].date)`?

Comment: no, date and time are separate

Comment: Done @Alfabravo

Comment: 'function' is a reserved word and one of your fields is using it: `mysql.escape(data[i].function)`

Comment: @Alfabravo, it works anyway, because 34 rows are already inserted this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `mysql.escape(data[i].title)` is already putting single quotes around your values, so you're doubling that up by adding them yourself.

Comment: Don't remove the scape, remove the single quotes you have in the string that you're explicitly putting in yourself.